# Java (follow up) - Morse Code program feedback says my code 40% correct

Tags: java

I am unsure how to count my string by 5 to then translate the morse code into numbers. I fried using a for loop and using if statements with a substring bt that doesn't seem to be working.

```
import acm.program.*;

public class MorseDecoder extends ConsoleProgram
{

public void run()
{
    int digit = 0;
    String question = readLine("Please enter the morse code: ");
    String morse = question.substring(30);

    for (int i = 0; i == question.length(); i += 5)
    {
        if (morse.equals(".----")) {
            digit = 1;
        }
        else if (morse.equals("..---")) {
            digit = 2;
            System.out.println(digit);
        }
        else if (morse.equals("...--")) {
            digit = 3;
            System.out.println(digit);
        }
        else if (morse.equals("....-")) {
            digit = 4;
            System.out.println(digit);
        }
        else if (morse.equals(".....")) {
            digit = 5;
            System.out.println(digit);
        }
        else if (morse.equals("-....")) {
            digit = 6;
            System.out.println(digit);
        }
        else if (morse.equals("--...")) {
            digit = 7;
            System.out.println(digit);
        }    
        else if (morse.equals("---..")) {
            digit = 8;
            System.out.println(digit);
        }
        else if (morse.equals("----.")) {
            digit = 9;
            System.out.println(digit);
        }
        else if (morse.equals("-----")) {
            digit = 0;
            System.out.println(digit);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("NaN");
        }
    }
}

//~ Methods ...............................................................

}
```

The following is an edit to my For loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i == question.length(); i += 5)
    {
        String morse = question.substring(i, i + 5);

        if (morse.equals(".----")) {
            digit = 1;
            System.out.println(digit);
        }
        else if (morse.equals("..---")) {
            digit = 2;
            System.out.println(digit);
        }
        else if (morse.equals("...--")) {
            digit = 3;
            System.out.println(digit);
        }
        else if (morse.equals("....-")) {
            digit = 4;
            System.out.println(digit);
        }
        else if (morse.equals(".....")) {
            digit = 5;
            System.out.println(digit);
        }
        else if (morse.equals("-....")) {
            digit = 6;
            System.out.println(digit);
        }
        else if (morse.equals("--...")) {
            digit = 7;
            System.out.println(digit);
        }    
        else if (morse.equals("---..")) {
            digit = 8;
            System.out.println(digit);
        }
        else if (morse.equals("----.")) {
            digit = 9;
            System.out.println(digit);
        }
        else if (morse.equals("-----")) {
            digit = 0;
            System.out.println(digit);
        }
        else if (morse.length() < 5) {
            System.out.println("NaN");
        }
    }
```

Edit: I have updated my code.

Comment: Since your program is deterministic (does not use random values), there can't be such thing as "working 40% of the times". There will be input upon with it *always* works, and inputs that *Always* break it. You should gather the non-working inputs, and make a table of expected vs. actual output, then try to analyse it, in order to figure out why things happen.

Comment: What kind of input is the user supposed to enter? Can you give an example?

Comment: an example would be: "....---..." which should output "47", or "....---...--" which should output "47NaN".

Comment: Your edit is still wrong. The `substring` you pull is the wrong index. Remember strings are zero based too so to get 5 chars you need 0,1,2,3,4. My answer solves your problem, check it out.

Answer (score 3):

You never set `morseDig` to anything other than "". I don't see how this program will ever work, even once.

In fact there are quite a few problems with your code, one pointed out by Steve P. in a useful answer that he deleted.

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand what to do with morseDig. I haven't done any coding with strings and this was thrown at me yesterday with essentially no instructions, so I'm very confused.

Comment: @user2926092: is this your real code? If so, how can it "work 40% of the time"? You have to assign morseDig to a morse code String derived from the input.

Comment: @user2926092: by "assign" I mean `morseDig = ....<something here> ....`. If the user is only entering one code, then you'll likely assign the whole input String to morseDig. Otherwise you'll want to `split` the input String into perhaps an array of Strings and analyze each one in a for loop.

Comment: I am wondering the same thing, but my online feedback says 40%. My guess is that my code is 40% correct, but nothing actually works.

Comment: @user2926092: that makes more sense, and is likely something you should put into your original question as an edit.

Comment: I tried making a substring to use in the if statements but that isn't working any better than before. Do you have any advice?

Comment: @user2926092: a substring made using a magic number (here 30) makes little sense to me. Why are you doing this? What is special about 30? Can you show us sample input as an edit to your question? Also, don't delete old code in your question, but add new code to the bottom. Otherwise you make our answers look nonsensical because the code that they refer to are no longer there.

Comment: Oh, I just realized why 30 wouldn't make sense. I mind lapse for a second and thought I needed to start at the end of the question, the 30th character, but that is nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

The only time you're printing besides the prompt is in:

```
else if (morseDig.equals("..---")) 
{
     digit = 2;
     System.out.println(digit);
}
```

and in:

```
else 
{ 
     System.out.println("NaN");
}
```

which is not the only issue (see @Hovercraft Full of Eels' answer).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Same to you :)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Fair enough, I didn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

I agree it looks like you have not set morseDig to anything except "".

you could use substring to get the five characters that you are looking for ex:
    morseDig = question.substring(i, i+5);

you may want to build a string to output your number from the morse code ex:
    String out ="";
then in each of your if or elseif statments just add the output to the string:
    out = out + 1;
etc.

after your loop just print the variable out to the screen.  I hope this helps with some of your problems.

Comment: I just edited my for loop to resemble that. Still no luck though.

Comment: Edit your substring so it is i, i +5. otherwise you are pulling 6 characters not 5.  With the current edit it will not work becuase there is no possible match.